# Why do Eigenvectors emerge as solutions to apparently unrelated problems?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Principal Component Analysis** - Eigenvectors of the covariance matrix is the best way (linear) to project the data into lower dimensional space.

**Page Rank Algorithm** - Principal eigenvector is the solution to the power iteration of the transition matrix.

**Image Segmentation** - Shi & Malik 2010: The eigenvector corresponding to the second smallest eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix partitions the graph into two tightly connected components.

There are others too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Applications

Aside from a technical response, I'm hoping for some insight.

Comment: You might as well ask: why are matrices important?

Answer (score 0):

I think the math helps show how these problems are not unrelated. The principal eigenvector of a matrix solves:

$$ x^* = \arg\max_{x: ||x||=1}{x^T A x}$$

When $A$ is a correlation matrix, this amounts to finding the collection of variables with the greatest mutually consistent correlations. (When our data matrix is standardized as in PCA, this will also maximize the variance of the data when projected onto this dimension.)

When $A$ is a stochastic matrix (nonnegative and having columns which sum to 1), it represents a markov chain, and the principal eigenvector is its stationary distribution (with eigenvalue 1), which is what PageRank is doing.

The image segmentation appears funky because it actually uses the second-smallest eigenvalue of the Laplacian matrix $(D - A)$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix of nodes' degrees and $A$ is the adjacency matrix. Intuitively, this flips the spectrum of the matrix such that the smallest eigenvalues are of interest (though I forget how we'd say this formally). The Laplacian's eigevector corresponding to eigenvalue $0$ is the all-ones vector $\mathbb{\vec{1}}$. Thus the next eigenvector solves an equation symmetric to the above but adding the constraint of orthogonality to the previous eigenvector:

$$ \arg\min_{x: \left(||x||=1 \,\, \wedge \,\, x \perp \vec{\mathbb{1}}\right) }{x^T L x}$$

Which can be roughly interpreted as finding the best one-dimensional representation of the graph which sums to zero.